# Add a mail template or without it sending mails in jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-boot, smtp, thymeleaf, jhipster

I need to add a mail template(abc.html) like default activationEmail.html, CreationEmail.html, passwordResetEmail.html inside the .../build/resources/main/mails/abc.html. When I manually created that abc.html and after I run gradlew to execute the app, that newly created abc.html file get deleted. So how I can create it? Do I need to register that file somewhere else?
 Is there any specific command to create the html file as creating an entity in jhipster. My final goal is to send a mail. But without creating the template I have no idea to pass the value for content variable in sendMail method in MailService.java. Assigning null for the content is also not worked. So is there any built in method to send mail without using templates?

```
@Async
public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
    log.debug("Send email[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
        isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

    // Prepare message using a Spring helper
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content, isHtml);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        log.debug("Sent email to User '{}'", to);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
        } else {
            log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}': {}", to, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Async
public void sendSportMail(String email,String message) {
    log.debug("Sending sports email to '{}'", email," message");
    Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en");
    String subject = messageSource.getMessage("email.reset.title", null, locale);
    Context context = new Context(locale);
    context.setVariable(BASE_URL, jHipsterProperties.getMail().getBaseUrl());
    String content = templateEngine.process("creationEmail", context);
    sendEmail(email, subject, content, false, true);
}
```

There inside sendSportMail method instead of "creationEmail", I need a value("abc") to pass. Or if there any way to send a mail without creating a template that is better. Because actually I don't need a mail template. I could retrieve values for email and message parameters in sendSportMail method. So I just need to send the mail where mail body is message and receiver's mail is email. Configurations for the gmail is done properly and worked well for already built in functions like password resetting, creating users and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create anything inside build/ folder as it is used by gradle to compile and package your project. It's similar to target/ folder for maven.

Create your html template inside src/main/resources/mails/ instead